# Почему PhpStorm автоматически изменяет пути к файлам?

Tags: phpstorm

Скачал последнюю 10 версию PHPStorm, создал PHP проект, добавил в него файлы из существующего сайта, настроил автоматический деплой, обновил, проиндексировал - все прекрасно! НО в бочке меда оказалась ложка дегтя, а именно, после открытия php файла-шаблона, IDE автоматически изменяет пути, дописывая к ним `/www/` в начало

Было:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/error_report.js"></script>
```

Открыл в редакторе, **стало**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/www/common/js/error_report.js"></script>
```

Струкрута проекта:
`cli` - скрипты, вне сайта
`www` - сайт

Деплой настроен:
`/var/www/cli` → `/cli`
`/var/www/html/www.site.ru/` → `/www`

Т.е. весьма "умный" IDE считает своим священным долгом автоматически, не спрашивая меня(!) взять и изменить в шаблоне пути к статике, а потом я сайт открываю и ничего не работает. Очень мудро. Где это настраивается, все настройки уже обрыл, метил папки как ресурсы, результат один -- после открытия файла IDE меняет пути к файлам, считая, что они непременно должны начинаться с `/www/`, но вдруг у меня url rewrite настроен или ещё что-то, зачем вот так брать и думать за меня?

Comment: Стало
<script type="text/javascript" src="/www/common/js/error_report.js"></script>

Comment: Для редактирования ответа есть кнопка-ссылка «Править» под метками.

Comment: не вижу разницы между двумя примерами